# Jgroups cluster breaks on restart of individual cluster members

Tags: jgroups

I am  experiencing  issue with  our jgroups  cluster loosing each other when a few cluster members restart.
We have 13 nodes in the cluster and all of them are in the same subnet . When restarting 4 of the nodes the entire cluster breaks down. All of the  of the members stop  recognizing  each other, and the existing members which were not restarted also do not find each other.

We start getting the SUSPECT messages and failed to collect all ACKs

0;33mWARN  [Incoming-1,broadcast,node-12] [GMS] node-12: failed to collect all ACKs (expected=11) for view [node-12|27] after 2000ms, missing 11 ACKs from node-12, node-4, node-6, node-13, node-11, node-2, node-7, node-8, node-9, node-0, node-3

0;33mWARN  [INT-2,broadcast,node-12] [FD] node-12: I was suspected by node-5; ignoring the SUSPECT message and sending back a HEARTBEAT_ACK

PFB the configuration we are using , please let me know if there any issue with the configuration . We are using 3.4.1.Final version of JGroups

```
<TCP loopback="true"
recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:20M}"
send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:640K}"
discard_incompatible_packets="true"
max_bundle_size="64K"
max_bundle_timeout=“5"
enable_bundling="true"
use_send_queues="true"
sock_conn_timeout="300"
timer_type="new"
timer.min_threads="4"
timer.max_threads="10"
timer.keep_alive_time="3000"
timer.queue_max_size="500"
thread_pool.enabled="true"
thread_pool.min_threads="1"
thread_pool.max_threads="10"
thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
thread_pool.queue_enabled=“true"
thread_pool.queue_max_size="100000"
thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"
oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1"
oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8"
oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard"
bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr}"
bind_port="${jgroups.bind_port}" />

<JDBC_PING connection_driver="${database.driver}"
            connection_password="${database.password}"
            connection_username="${database.user}"
            connection_url="${database.url}"
            initialize_sql="${jgroups.schema}"
    datasource_jndi_name="${datasource.jndi.name}"/>

    <MERGE2 min_interval="10000" max_interval="30000" />
    <FD_SOCK />
    <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500" />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK use_mcast_xmit="false" exponential_backoff="500" discard_delivered_msgs="true" />
    <UNICAST2 />
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="4M" />
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000" view_bundling="true" />
    <UFC max_credits="20M" min_threshold="0.4" />
    <MFC max_credits="20M" min_threshold="0.4" /`enter code here`>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K" />
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you restart your nodes? By killing them, or by a graceful shutdown (= cluster leave)?
A few comments to your config:

- The regular thread pool has only 1 thread running until the queue is full (100'000 elements), so there may be quite a few messages pending in the queue. I suggest disable the queue (`thread_pool.queue_enabled=“false"`), or increase the min number of threads and/or decrease the queue size (say 100)
- Try `TCPPING` instead of `JDBC_PING`, just to see if this helps
- Use `MERGE3` instead of `MERGE2`
- Use `NAKACK2` instead of `NAKACK`. In general, I suggest use `udp.xml` shipped with the version of JGroups you use, and apply my recommendations above. This prevents you from using old protocols.
- Use `FD_ALL` instead of `FD`
- A max credits of 20M is too much for `MFC`/`UFC` and effectively defeats the purpose of flow control.

Also run `probe.sh` (check the JGroups manual for details) to fetch information about the various protocols, e.g. thread pool usage in the transport (`TCP`), suspicions in `FD_ALL` etc.

Hope thi helps,

Comment: Good to hear this helped. Your thread pool config is still effectively single threaded though...